# How to create a UUID from a value

Tags: java, uuid

In my database, I have a uuid `67b26616-943e-49e0-a70c-8e9ddcba1baa`. In my code, I want to query the database and want to pass the above uuid. How could I create a type UUID from a value? I saw the following function but I dont know which bits of my value goes where.

```
public UUID(long mostSigBits,
    long leastSigBits)
```

Comment: [`UUID.fromString(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#fromString-java.lang.String-)

Comment: To add to what Tim has said, why cant you just use the String as is?

Comment: Do you mean UUID("67b26616-943e-49e0-a70c-8e9ddcba1baa")? It doesn't compile.

Comment: http://Iamnotbotheredbymyscore.Iamheretolearn

Comment: And honestly: if the above comments were not enough to get you going, and you don't understand the difference between calling a static method, and a constructor call - then seriously: consider stepping back from what you are doing right now. Because your knowledge seems to be so basic, that well: you shouldn't be touching data bases or any real world thing at this point in time.

Comment: http://gogetalife

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create UUID this way:-

```
UUID uid = UUID.fromString("67b26616-943e-49e0-a70c-8e9ddcba1baa");

System.out.println("UUID value is: "+uid);
```